# Getting a syntax error when trying to use JavaScript in dreamweaver CS6

Tags: javascript, dreamweaver

for some reason my code keeps getting syntax errors in dreamweaver CS6. This same code works on [www.codepen.co](http://www.codepen.co) this is a link to that code working: https://codepen.io/SabAsan/pen/ExVzaGb .
CS6 doesn't like the // after https: and gives it a new line whilst turning it into a comment regardless. I get a syntax error on the line before this anyways with the '=>' can someone help me out, am i missing something or is there differences between JS and JS on dreamweaver? Thanks in advance.

```
const html = document.documentElement;
const canvas = document.getElementById('hero-lightpass');
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');

const frameCount = 148;
const currentFrame = index => (
  `https:
//www.apple.com/105/media/us/airpods-pro/2019/1299e2f5_9206_4470_b28e_08307a42f19b/anim/sequence/large/01-hero-lightpass/${index.toString().padStart(4, '0')}.jpg`  
)

const preloadImages = () => {
  for (let i = 1; i < frameCount; i++) {
    const img = new Image();
    img.src = currentFrame(i);
  }
};
```

I have only added snippet of the code but the rest can be viewed on the link.

Comment: Dreamweaver is a code editor with some ability to interpret and highlight code. It will never execute it. Check what type of code it is parsing

Comment: I understand, but why would it be giving me a syntax error even if it isn't executing it? it doesn't work when i open the html on a browser either

Comment: Because it is parsing the code and trying to highlight what is mostly typos.

Comment: surely it would still work in google chrome though? but it still doesn't

Answer (score 0):

You are using template literals and arrow functions, both features introduced in [ECMAScript 2015](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#6th_Edition_%E2%80%93_ECMAScript_2015).

Dreamweaver CS6 was released in [2012](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Dreamweaver#Version_history). It is *really* old. There have been 8 major versions of Dreamweaver released since CS6.

It is likely highlighting syntax errors because you are using syntax too new for it to recognise.