# JavaScript code copied from code pen giving error

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new to HTML CSS and javascript. I did some coding on creating animated tabs with indicators using HTML, CSS & JavaScript. I am stuck with editing the JavaScript file and the error I am getting while editing this file and getting "syntax error in JavaScript" when using Dreamweaver IDE. I tried adding function keyword and closing / adding brackets but did not work so far.
Seems CSS working fine and I am stuck with writing the javascript file properly. There might not any syntax errors since it is working fine in the https://codepen.io/. When I am compiling it in the Adobe DreamViewer the software throws a Syntax error on the 1st line itself.

The reason behind me to think this is a javascript error is as I have shown in the example, unable to move between tabs of CODE, ABOUT, SERVICES, and CONTACT in the index.html page (Image attached).

[image: Chrome console result]

[image]

[image]

HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script src="myScript.js"></script>
</head>

<div class="tabs">
    <div class="tab-header">
        <div class="active">
                    <i class="fa fa-code"></i>Code
            </div>      
        <div>
                <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i>About
        </div>      
        <div>
                <i class="fa fa-bar-chart"></i>Services
        </div>      
        <div>
                <i class="fa fa-envelop-o"></i>Contact
        </div>          
    </div>      
    <div class="tab-indicator"></div>
    <div class="tab-body">
        <div class="active">
            <h2>This is code section</h2>
            <p>Test is all about fun</p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h2>This is about section</h2>
            <p>Test is all about fun</p>
        </div>      
        <div>
            <h2>This is services section</h2>
            <p>Test is all about fun</p>
        </div>      
        <div>
            <h2>This is section</h2>
            <p>Test is all about fun</p>
        </div>
        </div>  
</div>
</html>
```

JavaScript

```
let tabHeader = document.getElementsByClassName("tab-header")[0];
let tabIndicator = document.getElementsByClassName("tab-indicator")[0];
let tabBody = document.getElementsByClassName("tab-body")[0];

let tabsPane = tabHeader.getElementsByTagName("div");

for(let i=0;i<tabsPane.length;i++){
  tabsPane[i].addEventListener("click",function(){
    tabHeader.getElementsByClassName("active")[0].classList.remove("active");
    tabsPane[i].classList.add("active");
    tabBody.getElementsByClassName("active")[0].classList.remove("active");
    tabBody.getElementsByTagName("div")[i].classList.add("active");
    
    tabIndicator.style.left = `calc(calc(100% / 4) * ${i})`;
  });
}
```

CSS

```
body {
  background:#ddd;
  font-family:"Raleway";
}
.tabs {
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
  width:500px;
  height:250px;
  background:#f5f5f5;
  padding:20px 30px;
  overflow:hidden;
  border-radius:50px;
  box-shadow:5px 10px 5px #ccc;
}
.tabs .tab-header {
  height:60px;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
}
.tabs .tab-header > div {
  width:calc(100% / 4);
  text-align:center;
  color:#888;
  font-weight:600;
  cursor:pointer;
  font-size:14px;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  outline:none;
}
.tabs .tab-header > div > i {
  display:block;
  margin-bottom:5px;
}
.tabs .tab-header > div.active {
  color:#00acee;
}
.tabs .tab-indicator {
  position:relative;
  width:calc(100% / 4);
  height:5px;
  background:#00acee;
  left:0px;
  border-radius:5px;
  transition:all 500ms ease-in-out;
}
.tabs .tab-body {
  position:relative;
  height:calc(100% - 60px);
  padding:10px 5px;
}
.tabs .tab-body > div {
  position:absolute;
  top:-200%;
  opacity:0;
  transform:scale(0.9);
  transition:opacity 500ms ease-in-out 0ms,
    transform 500ms ease-in-out 0ms;
}
.tabs .tab-body > div.active {
  top:0px;
  opacity:1;
  transform:scale(1);
}
```

Comment: What **exactly** is the error, and what portion of the code causes it?

Comment: Your JavaScript code as posted does not give me a syntax error from Node.

Comment: If the HTML you show in the question is indeed the HTML you are running it has errors. There should not be spaces between class and its equals sign, nor after its equals sign and before the quotes. JS will have been unable to find elements. You should see in your browser's console log some errors which describe this.

Comment: @Pointy I have done this code learning through CodePen. there we don't have to declare functions as I feel. but when I copy the same code from CodePen JavaScript to Adobe Dreamweaver software  it says there is an error in 1st line it self and cannot check further syntax errors. Anyway expected results is not coming through Adobe Dreamweaver though i have done the  referencing part in html code.

Comment: @AHaworth Thanks for pointing out my mistake. I corrected it and updated the question. But my problem still persists.

Comment: There are still spaces either side of some of the equals signs in the HTML - these need to be removed.

Comment: @AHaworth Thanks for pointing the mistake again. I thought it is only applicable for class and its equal sign. I change the lang attribute as well and updated it. Thanks for prompt reply.

Comment: What version of dreamweaver is that?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63233155/getting-a-syntax-error-when-trying-to-use-javascript-in-dreamweaver-cs6

Comment: Dreamweaver added support for es6 in the October 2018 release of Dreamweaver (version 19.0)

Comment: @ksav Version 12.0 Build 5808. I checked this with notepad++ and it did not work either.

Comment: It might only support syntax for es5 javascript as it was released around April 2012

Comment: @AHaworth spaces around `=` in HTML markup are perfectly fine. [See this spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/syntax.html#elements-attributes) and note that the `=` can be surrounded by zero or more spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working fine. You are missing the body tag

```
</head>
<body>    <!-- Add this --- >

<div class="tabs">
.
 .
.
 .

   <div>
            <h2>This is section</h2>
            <p>Test is all about fun</p>
        </div>
        </div>  
</div>
</body> <!-- Add this --- >
</html>
```

```js
let tabHeader = document.getElementsByClassName("tab-header")[0];
let tabIndicator = document.getElementsByClassName("tab-indicator")[0];
let tabBody = document.getElementsByClassName("tab-body")[0];

let tabsPane = tabHeader.getElementsByTagName("div");

for(let i=0;i<tabsPane.length;i++){
  tabsPane[i].addEventListener("click",function(){
    tabHeader.getElementsByClassName("active")[0].classList.remove("active");
    tabsPane[i].classList.add("active");
    tabBody.getElementsByClassName("active")[0].classList.remove("active");
    tabBody.getElementsByTagName("div")[i].classList.add("active");
    
    tabIndicator.style.left = `calc(calc(100% / 4) * ${i})`;
  });
}
```

```css
body {
  background:#ddd;
  font-family:"Raleway";
}
.tabs {
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
  width:500px;
  height:250px;
  background:#f5f5f5;
  padding:20px 30px;
  overflow:hidden;
  border-radius:50px;
  box-shadow:5px 10px 5px #ccc;
}
.tabs .tab-header {
  height:60px;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
}
.tabs .tab-header > div {
  width:calc(100% / 4);
  text-align:center;
  color:#888;
  font-weight:600;
  cursor:pointer;
  font-size:14px;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  outline:none;
}
.tabs .tab-header > div > i {
  display:block;
  margin-bottom:5px;
}
.tabs .tab-header > div.active {
  color:#00acee;
}
.tabs .tab-indicator {
  position:relative;
  width:calc(100% / 4);
  height:5px;
  background:#00acee;
  left:0px;
  border-radius:5px;
  transition:all 500ms ease-in-out;
}
.tabs .tab-body {
  position:relative;
  height:calc(100% - 60px);
  padding:10px 5px;
}
.tabs .tab-body > div {
  position:absolute;
  top:-200%;
  opacity:0;
  transform:scale(0.9);
  transition:opacity 500ms ease-in-out 0ms,
    transform 500ms ease-in-out 0ms;
}
.tabs .tab-body > div.active {
  top:0px;
  opacity:1;
  transform:scale(1);
}
```

```html
<div class="tabs">
    <div class="tab-header">
        <div class="active">
                    <i class="fa fa-code"></i>Code
            </div>      
        <div>
                <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i>About
        </div>      
        <div>
                <i class="fa fa-bar-chart"></i>Services
        </div>      
        <div>
                <i class="fa fa-envelop-o"></i>Contact
        </div>          
    </div>      
    <div class="tab-indicator"></div>
    <div class="tab-body">
        <div class="active">
            <h2>This is code section</h2>
            <p>Test is all about fun</p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h2>This is about section</h2>
            <p>Test is all about fun</p>
        </div>      
        <div>
            <h2>This is services section</h2>
            <p>Test is all about fun</p>
        </div>      
        <div>
            <h2>This is section</h2>
            <p>Test is all about fun</p>
        </div>
        </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for showing the body tag and I added as    instructed.But still java script code error persists

Comment: That is not javascript error. Its the warning from dreamweaver. Try <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />

Comment: Thanks for your review. The reason behind me to think this is a javascript error is as I have shown in the example, unable to move between tabs of CODE, ABOUT, SERVICES, and CONTACT in the index.html page (Image attached in the question).

Comment: https://community.adobe.com/t5/dreamweaver/quot-there-is-a-syntax-error-on-line-x-quot/m-p/3862591   try this

Comment: If your viewing the page in chrome browser, then right click inspect element, click on console tab. It will show you what error you have in your javascript code. If your js code had errors, then it would not have run  the SO snippet.

Comment: I updated the question with the chrome console screenshot. Also referred to some answers given for such error. Thanks for the Guidance.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235236/discussion-between-alaksandar-jesus-gene-and-harsha-madusanka).